# NASM trouble with Windows 8.1 64-Bit

Tags: windows, cmd, compatibility, nasm

I'm having some trouble getting NASM to work at the moment. I have to get it installed for a subject that I'm doing at college. I have Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit installed. I managed to get NASM installed by downloading the latest version.

Our first task is just to copy the code to a Hello World program and get it running. Here's the code below:

```
            bits 16
            org 0x100       ; Start the program at offset 100h
            jmp main        ; Jump to main program
message:    db 'Hello World', 0ah, 0dh, '$'
main:       mov dx, message ; Start address of message
            mov ah, 09      ; Prepare for screen display
            int 21h         ; DOS interrupt 21h
            int 20h         ; Terminate program
```

So I saved that as prog1.asm and used a batch script that our lecturers gave us to compile it. The batch script is this:

```
nasm -f bin %1.asm -o %1.com -l %1.lst
```

When I type in `as prog1.asm` into cmd it compiles without error, although as soon as I type in `prog1` to run the program I get the following error in the cmd window:

`This version of C:\Users\########\AppData\Local\nasm\prog1.com is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.`

I don't know what to do really and no matter what I try or Google, nothing seems to give me a straight answer or a proper solution.

Comment: [NASM on win7 64 bit](http://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=830.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program you've built is a DOS program - it won't run directly in Windows (you might be able to run it in compability mode in Windows XP/9x, but certainly not on your 64-bit edition of Windows 8.1).

You'll need to run your program in some sort of emulator that can handle DOS programs. Probably the most popular one is DOSBox.

If you choose DOSBox you can use a 3rd party front-end to configure things. Or you can just start up DOSBox, then at DOSBox's prompt type:

```
mount c: <the directory where prog1.com is located>
c:
prog1
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Noted! I installed DOSBox now and ran the commands that you posted although nothing happens. It just has an empty line and then returns to waiting for a command.

If I try and re-compile the code in DOSBox, it tells me `This program cannot be run in DOS mode.`

Comment: If you instead of running `prog1` do `dir prog1` at the last step, does your COM file get listed? Just trying to make sure that you ended up in the right directory in DOSBox.

Comment: Yes, it does. Three files are listed: ASM, COM, LST.

Comment: I get `Hello World` when I try the same thing. I assembled with `nasm -f bin -o prog1.com prog1.asm` (I assembled in Windows' prompt, then ran the COM file in DOSBox).

Comment: What version of NASM are you using? Also what OS do you have?

Comment: nasm 2.10.07, DOSBox 0.74, Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Strange, I recompiled the asm file now and it worked like you said. If I compile in the Windows CMD and then run it in DOSBox it works! Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: Any other asm newbie that like me feels a bit sad when discovering that you cannot touch the CPU bare metal and have to go with an emulated CPU ? :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the same exercise.
I have Windows 7 64bit.
My solution was this:

1. Downloaded and Installed DosBox
2. Downloaded 16bit version of NASM from:
   http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/nasm/nsm09838.zip?download
   (other versions of NASM gave me weird errors)
3. Unzipped NASM to **c:\nasm16**
4. Using notepad, created prog1.asm file (with containing code) in c:\nasm16\
5. Copied the "as.bat" file into c:\nasm16\
6. Ran DosBox, and in Dosbox ran command:

> mount c c:\nasm16

7. Open mounted drive with command:

> c:\

8. ran command:

> as prog1

And it worked hooraa! :)